# manage some output based on some parameter and rtc

Tags: eeprom, loop, struct

i'm trying to create a program that given a configuration (i've used multiple struct nested) i need in loop() to check for each output if they need to be on or off and set the output accordingly

let me explain the configuration (i'm not sure that this is the best way to make and store this config, suggestions are appreciated)

```
struct Period
{
    String name;
    String type;
    String value;
};

struct State
{
    String name;
    Period periods[2];
};

struct Output
{
    String name;
    int pin;
    int forcePin;
    State states[2];
};

Output outputs[4];
```

now i populate the first object (this is something that need to be editable by the user and i was thinking to store it in the EEPROM, for now in the setup() i do this

```
    outputs[0].name = "OUTPUT 1";
    outputs[0].pin = 27;
    outputs[0].forcePin = 25;
    outputs[0].states[1].name = "STATE 1";
    outputs[0].states[1].periods[0].name = "day";
    outputs[0].states[1].periods[0].type = "BOOL";
    outputs[0].states[1].periods[0].value = "ON";
    outputs[0].states[1].periods[1].name = "night";
    outputs[0].states[1].periods[1].type = "BOOL";
    outputs[0].states[1].periods[1].value = "OFF";
    outputs[0].states[0].name = "STATE 2";
    outputs[0].states[0].periods[0].name = "day";
    outputs[0].states[0].periods[0].type = "BOOL";
    outputs[0].states[0].periods[0].value = "ON";
    outputs[0].states[0].periods[1].name = "night";
    outputs[0].states[0].periods[1].type = "BOOL";
    outputs[0].states[0].periods[1].value = "OFF";
```

then in the loop i have few function that determinate the state and period and i call this function that should manage all the outputs
globalState in loop read from an input and set the variable
globalPeriod check the time and set if night or day

```
void manageOutputs()
{
    for (Output out : outputs)
    {
        Serial.println(out.name);
        Serial.println(out.pin);
        Serial.println(out.forcePin);
        if (digitalRead(out.forcePin) == LOW)
        {
            Serial.println("forced on set output");
            digitalWrite(out.pin, HIGH)
            continue;
        }

        Serial.println(out.states[globalState].name);
        Serial.println(out.states[globalState].periods[globalPeriod].name);
        Serial.println(out.states[globalState].periods[globalPeriod].type);
        Serial.println(out.states[globalState].periods[globalPeriod].value);
        if (out.states[globalState].periods[globalPeriod].type.equals("BOOL")) {
            if (out.states[globalState].periods[globalPeriod].value.equals("ON")) {
                digitalWrite(out.pin,HIGH);
            } else {
                digitalWrite(out.pin,LOW);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i have multiple type of output in mind for example TIMER (so in the value field i would have some parameter to call another function that will alternate the output on and off for the time given) will have something like "15:10" so it will stay 15 minutes on and 10 minutes off, or a condition (for example if VAR1 > 50) so the field value would have "VAR1:>:50" so it will turn on only if the condition is met. So i will have a switch case where now i check if BOOL.

now that i hope that i have explained the situation, i would like to know if it's a good way to have 3 nested struct or if there is a better solution considering the necessity to have it stored in EEPROM, and if this is a good way to have this kind of condition like this or if there is a better way.
Considering also that in the future i would like to make a webpage or an api to update this kind of configuration from a pc (maybe using a esp-8266 for that, that is also connected to the arduino, or do everything with an esp32, but i would like first to have the basic loop working and then i will make the "UI")

thanks a lot

Comment: The 1st issue is this line: `digitalWrite(out.pin, HIGH)` with no semicolon. Next issue is `globalState` does not exist. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many uses of the `String` class in these code snippets. Using
strings is quite natural in some higher-level languages. On an Arduino,
however, I would strongly advise you against this for two reasons:

1. String objects use dynamic memory, which is not friendly to the small
   amount of RAM available on a typical Arduino.
2. Saving a String to EEPROM is not trivial: you do not want to save the
   String object (it contains a pointer that would not make sense in
   EEPROM context), and you instead have to save the character array it
   refers to. This could involve handling complex memory allocation
   withing the EEPROM.

Instead of a string meant to handle one of a predefined set of values
(`"BOOL"`, `"TIMER"`, ...), use an `enum`. This is similar to an `int`,
where each possible value has been given a name (`TYPE_BOOL` is 0,
`TYPE_TIMER` is 1, ...). Instead of a string holding numbers, store the
numbers themselves. In essence, you want to create a data storage format
that is friendly to the binary nature of the CPU. If you really have to
store strings, e.g. for names (are those `name` fields really useful?
they do not look so in the provided example), limit their length and
store them as fixed-size character arrays.

The `period::value` field is interesting in that it can store different
kinds of information depending on the `type` field. For such a situation
the appropriate data structure is a [discriminated union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). A `union`
is like a `struct` except that all fields share the same memory space
and only one can be valid at a time. In a discriminated union, the
`union` is accompanied by  a `ytpe` field that tells us which is the
valid field.

Applying those principles to your problem could give this kind of data
structure:

```cpp
// All the possible Period types.
enum Type {
    TYPE_BOOL,
    TYPE_TIMER,
    // etc.
};

// This is a discriminated union.
struct Period
{
    Type type;
    union {  // one union member per possible type.
        bool bool_value;  // valid when type == TYPE_BOOL
        struct {
            int on_time;
            int off_time;
        } timer_value;  // valid when type == TYPE_TIMER
        // etc.
    };
};

struct State
{
    Period periods[2];
};

struct Output
{
    int pin;
    int forcePin;
    State states[2];
};
```

These data structures can be trivially saved in EEPROM, as they are
self-contained: they hold no pointers to data stored in dynamic memory.

Then, in `manageOutputs()`, you will read a period's `bool_value` only
when `type` is `TYPE_BOOL`, it's `timer_value` only when `type` is
`TYPE_TIMER`, etc:

```cpp
void manageOutputs()
{
    for (Output out : outputs)
    {
        if (digitalRead(out.forcePin) == LOW) {
            digitalWrite(out.pin, HIGH);
            continue;
        }
        Period &period = out.states[globalState].periods[globalPeriod];
        switch (period.type) {
            case TYPE_BOOL:
                if (period.bool_value) {
                    digitalWrite(out.pin, HIGH);
                } else {
                    digitalWrite(out.pin, LOW);
                }
                break;
            case TYPE_TIMER:
                digitalWrite(out.pin, HIGH);
                delay(period.timer_value.on_time);
                digitalWrite(out.pin, LOW);
                delay(period.timer_value.off_time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the .name are useful to set a name on the output to be easy configurable and to be easier to understand what the output do (i don't think is necessary on the sub struct, but maybe on the main output, i will do some test with char array .. to see if it easy to work with that)